# Calculating Index of an address for set associative mapped cache

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, caching, associative

I have implemented a Direct Mapped Cache Simulation, now I want to implement set associative cache, for which I am using the following code for the calculation of index of an address from trace main memory references:

```
long index = ((address >> BLOCK_SHIFT) & (CACHE_SIZE - 1)) / 6;
```

where address is a trace main memory reference used for cache simulation, Block Shift is 5, for 32 bit cache Block size, and cache size is 1024.

Dividing by 6, to achieve associativity = 64 , as 2^6=64..

But this dividing by 6 is not giving right results..

Any ideas how to calculate index of an address for 64 bit associativity level..

Comment: re "Block Shift is 5, for 32 bit cache Block size": If the cache block size is 32 bit, shouldn't you right-shift by 32 bits instead of 5? DId I miss smething?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens dont understand, please explain, Block Size is mentioned by the User, and as 2^5=32, 5bits must be shifted from address...

Comment: **But it is a 32-bit cache-block, not a 5-bit cache-block**, 32 == 2^5 not withstanding.

Comment: you mean to say i shift the address 32 bits, it is giving a complete wrong cache hits and misses..

Comment: Then explain your question better. Your current explanation seems to make it obvious (IMHO) that 32 is correct and 5 incorrect. Nobody else is even looking at helping you  right now, as your post is currently written.

Comment: I am just searching, how to implement a 2 way set associative cache, Any help...